# Left invertible matrix over a division ring

Tags: ring-theory, noncommutative-algebra, division-ring

Is it true that every left invertible square matrix Α over a division ring R is also right invertible? If that is the case and B is the left inverse of A and C is the right inverse of A , then B=C?

Edit: for the second question we have that, C=InC=(BA)C=B(AC)=BIn=B (where In is the identity matrix).

Any thoughts on the the 1st question?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Yes. The exact same proof [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3860/29335) works.  It's possible because the familiar theory of bases from linear algebra also works for division rings.